# Angular UI-Router not loading anything

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

When I double click the index.html the browser only loads the nav-bar, the contents inside `partial-home.html` is not showing.

**app.js**

This is the app.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
    })

    // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
    .state('about', {
        // we'll get to this in a bit       
    });

});
```

**index.html**

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style>
    .navbar { border-radius:0; }
 </style>

<!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js</script>
<script>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="routerApp">

   <!-- NAVIGATION -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
 <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
  </div>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>

 <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
 <div class="container">

 <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT      ============================== -->
 <div ui-view></div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**partial-home.html**

This is the partial-home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
 <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
 <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying "I double click index.html" you mean that you are opening the file with your browser?

If yes it could be the problem. You need to load it on a web server.

You can do that with [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

- First install [node.js](https://nodejs.org) if you don't have it.
- Then install live-server with this command : `npm install -g live-server`
- Then go to your working directory and launch the server with this command : `live-server`

Your browser should launch your app. The URL shouls be like this: `http://localhost/...` which means you are on your web server!

Comment: plzz..can you tell me how to

Comment: I edited my post to explain you a procedure. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tIak1lMgQEy3RadtyB8?p=preview)

I just changed your `<script>` settings:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"
        ></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@*" 
        src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"
        ></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

The rest is the same as above. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tIak1lMgQEy3RadtyB8?p=preview)

Comment: I saw the example and yes it is working...but sadly am still getting the error..the partial-home.html is not loading

Comment: Where locally? or in my plunker?

Comment: Do you know what? I really would strongly suggest - copy paste my code from plunker into your local solution. all files index.html, app.js and partial html. And it should work even locally. If that is running in the plunker it must run at your local environment

Comment: I did that too...still no use.. :(

Comment: Look, I can hardly assist... because it is really local. My last guess is - some incorrect spelling in your template file name. Check twich that it is in same folder as index.html and that the name is correct

Comment: I downloaded the files from plunker and still not working...anyway thanks for the help :)